# Data survey using weight

Tags: r, syntax, glm, survey, weighted

I have survey data l and i need to make some tables and regression analyses on the data. We used PPS (probability proportional to size) with linear systematic sampling, which is carried out in two stages for the sampling method.
Here is some additional info from the data:

```
id class, id individu, weight,PSU,and starata
Variabels Y , X1,X2,X3,X4
```

So, how can I do the analyses regression logit for the weighted data?

Comment: Can you attach your data, and explain in detail what you are trying to do? If you have a weight variable in your data, you can simply use `weights=` as a parameter in `lm()` call, and multiply your observations with the weight variable for tabulation.

Comment: You can't just use a `weights=` argument in, eg, `lm()`, because the standard errors will be wrong.  You can use the `survey` package, though.